# possibly should vs should possibly, etc

Tags: expressions, word-order, word-difference

> (**A**) You possibly/probably **should**

vs

> (**B**) You **should** possibly/probably

I'm more used to the latter (the ones in B), but can I have a couple of examples for the first one (the ones in A)?

Comment: The meanings of "possible" and "probable" are different enough that a dictionary should give you an answer.

Comment: @Andrew: I think you (and J.R.) have mistaken what the question is asking about as being about possibly vs probably, when it's actually about word order for *both* possibly *and* probably when combined with "should".

Comment: @NathanTuggy it's possibly/probably because of Jake's use of "the latter" which suggests he thinks B is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases adverbs *(possibly/probably)* come after the verb.

- You **should** possibly/probably - is better in most circumstances.

The choice of (A) would be appropriate if you wish to emphasize or stress something.

- You should go for a walk and rest a little!
- Yes. I probably should do it!

**Note!** Here, the word order of choice (A) is appropriate:

- You should probably do take the bus instead."
- Yes. I probably should."